# Smooth and surjective morphisms of stacks admits local sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be a scheme with a smooth surjective morphism onto a stack $X\to \cal X$. Why does it admit local sections?

In [Why a smooth surjective morphism of schemes admits a section etale-locally?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/why-a-smooth-surjective-morphism-of-schemes-admits-a-section-etale-locally) is explained how to prove this fact if $\cal X$ is also a scheme, but I don't see how to generalise to stacks this result.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "locally". If $X\to Y $ is a smooth surjective morphism, then the induced morphism $X\times_Y X \to X$ admits a section (use fibre product properties). As the morphism $X\to Y$ is smooth surjective, you see that $X\to Y$ admits sections "locally for the smooth topology".

Comment: By a morphism $F: \cal Y \to \cal X$ of stacks admitting local section I mean that for each object $x \in \cal {X} (S)$  there exists an étale covering map $g:U\to S$, an object $y\in \cal {Y} (U)$ and a morphism $F(y)\to x$ over $g$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will follow the notation in the OP's comment on the question.

Given $x:S \to \mathcal X$, pull-back the given smooth surjective morphism $X \to \mathcal X$ to obtain a smooth morphism $T \to S$.

I am going to assume that $\mathcal X$ is an algebraic stack; then (by definition) its diagonal is representable by an algebraic space, and so, since $S$ is a scheme, the pull-back $T$ is an algebraic space.  Thus we can find a surjective etale morphism $U \to T$ with $U$ a scheme.

The composite morphism $U\to T \to S$ is then smooth and surjective, and the composite morpism $U \to T \to X$ lifts $x$.  We have thus made a smooth-local lift of $x$.

Now any smooth morphism $U \to S$ of schemes admits an etale local section, i.e. we can find $V \to S$ etale and surjective which lifts to a morphism $V \to U.$  The composite $V \to U \to X$ is then an etale local lift of $x$, as required.